# Unspecified Error After creating AMO programmatically

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssas, bids

I have programmatically created the Basic AM Objects(AMO) for Oracle and It went well ,

To verify the created components I'm using BIDS and When I'm clicking the "Explore Data" Command from action menu It's prompting Error ,

[image: Explre Data Action in BIDS]

And the Error is

[image: Error]

### TITLE: OraOLEDB

Unspecified error: E_FAIL(0x80004005)

---

BUTTONS:

&Retry

### Cancel

My Codes are as follows

```
private string oraconString = @"Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=( DESCRIPTION = ( ADDRESS_LIST = ( ADDRESS = ( PROTOCOL = TCP )( HOST = cmbtrndb02 )( PORT = 1521 ) ) )( CONNECT_DATA = ( SERVER = DEDICATED )( SERVICE_NAME = hector ) ) ); User Id= trnint16; Password = trnint16;";

static DataSourceView CreateDataSourceView(Database db, string strDataSourceName)
    { 
        //Create the Datasource View

        DataSourceView dsv = db.DataSourceViews.FindByName(strDataSourceName);

        if (dsv != null)
            dsv.Drop();

        dsv = db.DataSourceViews.Add(strDataSourceName);
        dsv.DataSourceID = strDataSourceName;
        dsv.Schema = new DataSet();
        dsv.Schema.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

        //Open a connection to the DataSource 

        // Testing the oledb connection is working with ODP parameters 

        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(dsv.DataSource.ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();

        #region Create tables
        //Add table FACTITSLA

        AddTable(dsv, connection, "FACTITSLA");

        dsv.Update();
        #endregion


        return dsv;




    }
```

What could be the reason for this error ?

Comment: No I've the the complete access to the database via Oracle SQL Developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error

> 80004005

is permissions, somewhere along the line. Unsure where in your scenario.

Comment: probably that user has restricted permissions on the database